# Turning coefficients on and off R linear regression

Tags: r, regression, coefficients

I want to create a linear regression model to predict an output that uses two different coefficients based on some threshold within the data. For example:
df:

```
Value   Temperature
 8.2     70
 3.2     51
 5.8     54
 7.2     61
```

and so on. For this data, I want to figure out how to make the following model:

Value = B0 + B1(HighTemp) + B2(LowTemp)

Where B1 is 0 if the temperature is below 55, and B2 is 0 is the temperature is above 55.
I tried the following:

```
fit = lm(Value ~ I(Temperature > 55), data = df)
fit2 = lm(Value ~ Temperature * I(Temperature > 55), data = df)
```

`fit` only gives me a coefficient for when the temperature is above 55, and `fit2` gives output that I don't fully understand. I was also thinking of creating a third column, `HighorLow`, with an indicator variable (1 or 0) for whether or not the temperature is high or low. The I would have:

```
fit = lm(Value ~ Temperature:HighorLow, data = df)
```

Does anyone have any input? I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You have two continuous variables, why do you want to use a threshold? Your linear regression could just be

```
df<-data.frame(Value=c(8.2,3.2,5.8,7.2),Temperature=c(70,51,54,61))
lm(Value~Temperature,data=df)
```

But if you really want to split into groups based on a threshold,

```
df$Temp_threshold<-df$Temperature>55
lm(Value ~ Temp_threshold,data=df)
```

Comment: This will give values for the intercept and Temp_thresholdTRUE. Which I assume is the coefficient for the temperature term when temperature is greater than 55. But what about the coefficient for the term below 55? I think there may be a fundamental concept that I'm not grasping.

Comment: You may want to read up on regression a little. Short answer - since you have two groups to compare (Temp_thresholdTRUE and Temp_thresholdFalse), the regression will implicitly calculate the coeff of one relative to the other, there aren't two coefficients. So the coefficients for Temp_thresholdTRUE quantifies the effect of TemperatureTRUE as compared to TemperatureFALSE (which is assumed to have no effect for simplicity).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of your third idea, which is the statistically appropriate one. You were correct to factor it.

```
> df <- data.frame(Value = runif(100, min = 0, max = 10), Temperature = runif(100, min = 50, max = 90))
> df$Threshold <- with(df, factor(ifelse(Temperature > 55, 1, 0)))
> m <- lm(Value ~ Threshold, data = df)
> summary(m)

Call:
lm(formula = Value ~ Threshold, data = df)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.9916 -2.1260  0.1069  2.4733  4.8550 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   5.4835     0.8155   6.724 1.19e-09 ***
Threshold1   -0.7074     0.8645  -0.818    0.415    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 2.705 on 98 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.006787,  Adjusted R-squared:  -0.003347 
F-statistic: 0.6697 on 1 and 98 DF,  p-value: 0.4151
```

Comment: So if I were to write this result out as a model, what would the coefficients for the high and low temperature be? For example, in my original post I had B1 and B2 for high and low temperature coefficients, which would 'turn on' or 'turn off' based on the indicator

Comment: @DellM The `Threshold` variable is an indicator (or "dummy") variable that is 1 when `Temperature > 55` and 0 otherwise. So the interpretation is if the `Temperature` is over 55, then use the coefficient for `Threshold`, otherwise you are multiplying by the value of `Threshold`, which is 0, so the term will be 0.

Comment: Can I add in a another term to describe the contribution of temperatures below 55, in addition to the contribution from temperature above 55?

Comment: I know you are looking for a second coefficient for easy interpretation, but adding another variable is duplicating information... the method above is the standard method of dealing with a binary variable in linear regression.

Comment: @DellM here is a great reference book for linear models in R: http://home.ufam.edu.br/jcardoso/PPGMAT537/Linear%20Models%20with%20R.pdf